# How to use model.predict?

Tags: tensorflow.js

Im importing  objects from json into tf.tensor2d. Objects with numbers  > 50 are labeled as bigger and < smaller.

```
 var irisTesting = [{"track": 40,"clan": "smaller"},{"track": 
 2,"clan" : 
 "smaller"},{"track": 99,"clan": "bigger"},];

 const trainingData = tf.tensor2d(iris.map(item => [
   item.track,
 ]))
 const outputData = tf.tensor2d(iris.map(item => [
   item.clan === "bigger" ? 1 : 0,
   item.clan === "smaller" ? 1 : 0,
 ]))
 const testingData = tf.tensor2d(irisTesting.map(item => [
   item.track,
 ]))
```

The predictions are extremely off. The tensor looks like this

```
 Tensor
      [0.0224216, 0.0128847],
      [0.0224305, 0.0128918],
      [0.0224216, 0.0128847]]
```

irisTesting has over 5000 labels. I am exspecting first to arrays as smaller then bigger. Instead it reads bigger with higher percentage. Am I reading this right? This is first time using tensorflowjs and my understanding on how to use model.predict function.

```
const model = tf.sequential()

model.add(tf.layers.dense({
  inputShape: [1],
  activation: "sigmoid",
  units: 5,
}))
model.add(tf.layers.dense({
  inputShape: [5],
  activation: "sigmoid",
  units: 2,
}))
model.add(tf.layers.dense({
  activation: "sigmoid",
  units: 2
}))
model.compile({
  loss: "meanSquaredError",
  optimizer: tf.train.adam(.06),
})
// train/fit our network
const startTime = Date.now()
model.fit(trainingData, outputData, {epochs: 100})
  .then((history) => {
    // console.log(history)
    model.predict(testingData).print()
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.  Your data is labeled as 1 and 0, I think your model structure is not aligned.  Additionally, I'm noticing you're using some "classical" activation and loss functions.  Might I suggest we tighten things up a little?

## Activation updates

You have 3 layers, all of them using sigmoid.

While this is doable, let's maybe move the first two layers to "relu" which will likely improve performance.  Relu is generally considered one of the best activation functions to use for these intermediate layers.

## Final layer

You're getting two sigmoid values.  Both are predicting how likely the clan is "bigger" or "smaller".  Since you're looking for true/false, and your data is labeled 1 and 0, it looks to me like you're really wanting to move to a single output here, with 1 being 100% sure of bigger, and 0 is 0% chance of bigger being true.  This would fit your input labels better, yes?

To do this, you'd keep your final layer as sigmoid, but only 1 unit!  You'll also have to change your compile loss function to `binaryCrossentropy`.

---

With this, you should be able to train and get a single output of % prob of "Bigger" which was labeled as 1